# R shiny segfaulting

Tags: r, shiny

I have just installed shiny 1.0.5 in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and am receiving a segmentation fault on the default landing page. The last bit of the Javascript console/hello error log is:

```
89: .Call("httpuv_run", PACKAGE = "httpuv", timeoutMillis)
90: run(timeoutMs)
91: service(timeout)
92: serviceApp()
93: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = function(e) {    if (is.null(attr(e, "stack.trace", exact = TRUE))) {        calls <- sys.calls()        attr(e, "stack.trace") <- calls        stop(e)    }})
94: captureStackTraces({    scheduleFlush()    while (!.globals$stopped) {        serviceApp()        Sys.sleep(0.001)    }})
95: ..stacktraceoff..(captureStackTraces({    scheduleFlush()    while (!.globals$stopped) {        serviceApp()        Sys.sleep(0.001)    }}))
96: runApp(Sys.getenv("SHINY_APP"), port = port, launch.browser = FALSE)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
-su: line 1:  2739 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) R --no-save --slave -f \/opt\/shiny-server\/R\/SockJSAdapter\.R
```

Also, from the beginning of the log file:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xbd, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Any tips on debugging this and getting it running?

Answer (score 0):

I don't ultimately know what the issue is, but upgrading to R 3.4.2 had completely broken Shiny. Removing r-base (r-base-core, etc) via apt and reinstalling 3.3.3 fixed the issue, though it remains frustrating.